# Android C++ NDK

Tags: c++, android, android-ndk

I am trying to compile the following for the android ndk

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <string.h>

extern "C" {
    JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_com_knucklegames_helloCpp_testFunction(JNIEnv * env, jobject obj);
};

JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_com_knucklegames_helloCpp_testFunction(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj) {
 return env->NewStringUTF(env, "Hello from native code!");
}
```

but it is giving the following error

```
Compile++ thumb: helloCpp <= /cygdrive/c/workspace/helloCpp/jni/main.cpp
/cygdrive/c/workspace/helloCpp/jni/main.cpp: In function '_jstring* Java_com_knucklegames_hello
Cpp_testFunction(JNIEnv*, _jobject*)':
/cygdrive/c/workspace/helloCpp/jni/main.cpp:10: error: no matching function for call to '_JNIEn
v::NewStringUTF(JNIEnv*&, const char [24])'
/cygdrive/d/android/android-ndk-r4b/build/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/include/jni.h:839: note: candidates
 are: _jstring* _JNIEnv::NewStringUTF(const char*)
make: *** [/cygdrive/c/workspace/helloCpp/obj/local/armeabi/objs/helloCpp/main.o] Error 1
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The NewStringUTF function only takes one argument, a c-string:

```
env->NewStringUTF("Hello from native code!");
```

There is a C version that goes like this:

```
NewStringUTF(env, "Hello from native code!");
```

But you are obviously using the C++ version.

Comment: Thanks this solved the error, but it is now force closing when trying to load the libary. It is in lib folder under the name of libhelloCpp.so and static { System.loadLibrary("helloCpp"); } is the problem

Comment: If you have another question, you should make another post.  More people are likely to see it that way.

Comment: Make sure that the .so is under libs/armeabi ; when the APK is installed to the device, you should see it under /data/data/com.knucklegames.helloCpp/lib/libhelloCpp.so

Comment: +1 Thanks for sharing; this was unclear from the docs I could find online.